Who are the real "experts" in quantitative finance we could contact to help improve the site?
Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky mention in podcast #30 that they would like to contact true experts in quantitative finance to evaluate this site, perhaps showing them 10 sample questions and paying them an honorarium to give their recommendations (and possibly contribute better answers). However, they say they do not know that much about quantitative finance and are not sure who to contact.  Do you like this idea?  Who would you recommend they contact?

We don't need to pay anyone to know that there's a severe quality gap on Quant SE. The real question is how to get high-caliber people to participate here in the first place. For that, seek out the ones that are actively online already, like bloggers, etc. That's whom we should be looking for.

Does SE have the resources to buy answers from the right caliber guys? I think it needs to be voluntary and persistent.

Will we announce the sample questions we choose before submission? It will give the us a final chance to revise these questions and answers.

@Branson well, that begs the question of whether we want the 10 questions to be "representative" or whether we want them to be examples of the best this site can produce.  I'm not sure what Joel had in mind.

I'd recommend in no particular order anyone from the following.
Academics

Atillio Meucci - he is quite active on www.symmys.com, Baruch, GARP
Frank Fabozzi - Yale, CFA Institute affiliation
Liuren Wu - Baruch
Andrew Lo - MIT / AlphaSimplex
Rene Carmona - Princeton
Rama Cont - Columbia
Doug Martin - U. Washington / FinAnalytica
Jim Gatheral - Baruch / ex-Merrill
John Cochran - U Chicago
C.M. Carvalho - U. Texas
Michael Johannes - Columbia
Andrew Ang - Columbia
Hedibert Lopes - U Chicago
Mike West - Duke
Mark Joshi - Melbourne University
Robert Almgren - NYU / Quantitative Brokers
Dani Gamerman - Instituto de Matemática 
Gregory Connor - London School of Economics

Practitioners

Bernd Scherer - EDHEC
Peter Carr - MS
Neil Chriss - Hutchin Hill
Cliff Asness - AQR
Mark Kritzman - NYU / Wyndham
Sebastian Ceria - Axioma 
Mark Carhart - Kepos
Bruno Dupire - Bloomberg
Fabio Mercurio - Bloomberg
Eric Sorenson - Panagora
Ronald Kahn
Richard Grinold (retired)
Emanuel Derman (retired)
Bob Litterman (retired)


+1 for Meucci, it would be really good to have this guy.

I remember Bob Litterman! He was old(er) when I was young. But I didn't know he retired. I still see his name from time to time online. I have thoughts on some of the others, but it would be gratuitous to make idle remarks and statements of opinion, positive or negative here. A very nice list, by the way! I just noticed it now. EDIT Mark Joshi is good to have here, but is probably very busy (I just noticed his name on the list, and as a QF SE member).

For those who might have missed a couple of threads on the main site, please note that Mark Joshi has already joined Quant SE!

Dominic Connor has joined the community today.
